# pattern matching for a string of specific length in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query for rows from a table where one of columns matches a string whose defining characteristic is an alphanumeric string of specific length (say 4) followed by a ":" followed by an integer.

- pattern : alphanumericstring : integer
- example1: 1234:someint
- example2: abcd:someotherint

I tried the following

```
select * from mytable where col1 like '[]{4}:%' 

select * from mytable where col1 like '.{4}:%'
```

and neither of these work. I am aware I didn't even try to ensure that the piece following the ":" was an integer.

Comment: What SQL server? Many support regular expression matches. E.g in Postgresql: `select * from mytable where col1 ~ '.{4}:[1-9][0-9]+'`

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: there is no regex support in SQL Server up to now; you have to expose .NET functionality via CLR function to get that

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Ah, I didn't see the `sql-server` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `charindex`, `substring` and `isnumeric`

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    col1 varchar(20),
    col2 varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
    VALUES 
    ('ABCD:123', 'Value 123'),
    ('1234:1234', 'Value 1234'),
    ('xyz:1234', 'should not be selected'),
    ('cdef:abcd', 'should not be selected too')


SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(':', col1, 0) = 5 AND 
      ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX(':', col1) + 1, 20)) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't directly support regular expressions (if you search around, you can probably find some tutorials for adding them via user-defined functions).

`LIKE` doesn't support quantifiers, but it does have wildcards and lightweight character classes.

An underscore will match any character:

```
SELECT col1
FROM data
WHERE col1 LIKE '____:%';
```

Or you can specify range(s) of characters to match:

```
SELECT col1
FROM data
WHERE col1 LIKE '[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:%';
```

See these [live on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fcec/2).

To specify that the second part must consist of digits only, an additional condition could be used:

```
SELECT col1
FROM data
WHERE col1     LIKE '[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:%'
  AND col1 NOT LIKE '[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:%[^0-9]%';
```

You can [test the last one live as well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d536/1).

Comment: All of your suggestions worked for me. Thank you for introducing me to SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It is ugly, but this should solve your problem for positive integers:

```
;WITH test AS (
  SELECT expr = '1234:3421'
  UNION ALL SELECT '1234:25'
  UNION ALL SELECT '1234:xx')
select * 
from test
where 
  expr like '%:[0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR expr like '%:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```